# Tear chimney down below roof line

Tags: ventilation

I have a hot water tank venting through the chimney.  The chimney on the roof needs replacing which is expensive. Could I tear the chimney down, anchor 4-inch PVC to chimney below roof line and would that provide adequate ventilation?

Comment: you have not provided enough information that can be used to formulate a meaningful answer

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. As @jsotola said, we'll need more information to help you. Is this is a gas DHW heater, and you want to vent its burner fumes? If so, I'm guessing PVC won't cut it.

Comment: Voting to close. OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of water heaters, standard efficiency and high efficiency. A standard efficiency water heater needs to be vented through the roof at least 12” and more if you are anticipating snow accumulation or the roof is pitched more than 4/12. It needs to be metal and usually double wall type B vent. There are some exceptions but these are usually a lot more expensive. For high efficiency water heaters often times PVC pipe is acceptable and often times it can vent out a side wall. Venting varies for these types and you will have to consult the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you need a masonry chimney to vent your water heater?** No. Double-walled metal duct rated for the task is common. PVC is suitable under more limited circumstances.

**Will you save money by avoiding a re-build of the masonry chimney?** I’m not so sure. Much of what you are paying for with a rebuild of that chimney is not in laying the bricks. You will still have to do a demo of the existing chimney above the roofline then install and weather seal a replacement. The footprint on your roof may be much smaller. Do you plan to re-shingle? How will the end result look?